# understanding the code from transit.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through the source of transit.js and came across the following fucntion ::

```
  $.cssHooks['transit:transform'] = {
    // The getter returns a `Transform` object.
    get: function(elem) {
      return $(elem).data('transform') || new Transform();
    },

    // The setter accepts a `Transform` object or a string.
    set: function(elem, v) {
      var value = v;

      if (!(value instanceof Transform)) {
        value = new Transform(value);
      }

      // We've seen the 3D version of Scale() not work in Chrome when the
      // element being scaled extends outside of the viewport.  Thus, we're
      // forcing Chrome to not use the 3d transforms as well.  Not sure if
      // translate is affectede, but not risking it.  Detection code from
      // http://davidwalsh.name/detecting-google-chrome-javascript
      if (support.transform === 'WebkitTransform' && !isChrome) {
        elem.style[support.transform] = value.toString(true);
      } else {
        elem.style[support.transform] = value.toString();
      }

      $(elem).data('transform', value);
    }
  };
```

I understand the latter part of the function, but its really hard to understand the initial part of the function, the function can be found on git too , **[HERE](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit/blob/master/jquery.transit.js#L149)** .

Initially I see this, `$.cssHooks['transit:transform']` what is that line really saying?

After that we have the below line of code  I.E. the getter and setter method,

```
set: function(elem, v) {
```

But who is passing the elem and v inside the function, I don't see anything being passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about cssHooks at [jQuery cssHooks](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/)

Look at the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js) (search for `hooks.get` and `hooks.set`)

`.cssHooks` is an `array` of `objects` that contains *getter* and *setters* tha will be executed by `.css()`. Thats all.

```
    $.cssHooks['transit:transform'] = {set: function(elem,value){}, get: function(elem){}}
     equal:
    $.cssHooks['transit:transform'] = {};
    $.cssHooks['transit:transform'].set = function(elem, value){};
    $.cssHooks['transit:transform'].get = function(elem){};

    $(element).css('transit:transform',value)
     comes to:
    $.cssHooks['transit:transform'].set(element,value)

    $(element).css('transit:transform')
     comes to:
    $.cssHooks['transit:transform'].get(element)
```

`$.cssHooks['transit:transform'] = {set:function(){}, get: function(){} }`

`{...}` is an object creation.
`get` and `set` not executed at this moment.
They created `{set:function(){}, get: function(){} }`

---

So. Simply: `.css()` will execute `set` and `get` functions for hooked property.

---

If you want to know how *real* getters and setters works:
[Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Please remove your last paragraph, this has nothing to do with `Object.defineProperty`

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you can add/access to a property with this syntax :

```
myObject.myProperty
```

or with this syntax :

```
myObject['myProperty']
```

This is the same result

So your line

```
$.cssHooks['transit:transform']
```

just mean that we want to store an object (code between {} in your original post) inside the 'transit:transform' property which is inside the cssHooks property which is inside the $ object

This is the same things :

```
$['cssHooks']['transit:transform']
```

The reason why they use the [''] syntax is that transit:transform contains  the ':' char which is not allowed if you want to access it this way :

```
$.cssHooks.transit:transform //doesn't work
```

**EDIT:**

To answer to your second question, i don't know...the code you are showing is just the 'description' of the "transit:transform' property

Comment: ! very well explained but i was looking for a more contextual answer